# Flutter - Some Input Files Look or override a depreciated API

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am receiving this warning while running my flutter application. Any ideas on how to resolve it?
[image]

Comment: You have to change the version of firebase dependencies in pub.yml

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wait for the plugin to get updated, and then obviously update your app to the version that stops using deprecated versions.